# Set unit for number_to_currency with a user setting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, currency

I want to allow users to change the currency unit throughout their account.

The obvious way to do it is to pass the `unit` parameter to `number_to_currency`, but given `number_to_currency` is used hundreds of times throughout the app, it seems a little repetitive to do that.

So is there some way to change what unit is used for all instances of `number_to_currency` based on a setting stored in the database for each user?

Comment: Do you need to just change the currency symbol, or to convert too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need some sort of global function / variable to define the symbol

I would do it like this:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def unit
    User.find(current_user.id).select(:currency_type) #I don't know how your units are stored - you may need logic to return the correctly formatted unit
end
```

This will allow you to call: `<%= number_to_currency, unit: unit %>`

---

**Overriding Helper Method**

`number_to_currency` is literally just a helper itself, which means you can append options on the fly:

Original

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb, line 106
      def number_to_currency(number, options = {})
        return unless number
        options = escape_unsafe_delimiters_and_separators(options.symbolize_keys)

        wrap_with_output_safety_handling(number, options.delete(:raise)) {
          ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_currency(number, options)
        }
      end
```

Amended

```
#app/helpers/application_herlper.rb
  def number_to_currency(number, options ={})
      unit = User.find(current_user.id).select(:currency_type)
      options[:unit] = unit unless options[:unit].present?
      super
  end
```

Comment: Yeah, like I mentioned, this is what I was hoping to avoid...setting the `unit` parameter ever single time I use `number_to_currency`.

Comment: Updated answer for you

Comment: Note, you can just call `current_user.currency_type` from the view, you don't need to run the sql query every time you call `number_to_currency`

Answer (score 4):

You could pass the currency as an option to the `number_to_currency` method as shown:

```
number_to_currency(1234567890.506, locale: :fr)
```

In that case you would need to replace `:fr` to whatever points to the user's setting and to create such a locale with such options:

```
number:
  currency:
    format:
      unit: '€'
      format: '%n %u'
      separator: ","
      delimiter: "."
      precision: 2
      significant: false
      strip_insignificant_zeros: false
```

Or you set the unit in another way:

```
number_to_currency(1234567890.50, unit: "&pound;", format: "%u %n")
 => "&pound; 1.234.567.890,50"
```

Hope this helps you.